# How to invoke _Verify_range for std::vector in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::back_inserter;


int main(void) {

    vector<int> coll1 {1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<int> coll2;

    copy(coll1.begin(), coll1.end(), back_inserter(coll2));

    const auto start = coll2.cbegin();
    const auto stop = coll2.cend();

    // start: class std::_Vector_const_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<int> > >
    cout << typeid(start).name() << endl;

    // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL: 2
    cout << _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL << endl;

    std::_Verify_range(start, stop);

    for (auto ele: coll2)
        cout << ele << ", " << ele << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile error:

```
error C2672:  'std::_Verify_range': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784:  'void std::_Verify_range(const std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> &,const std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> &) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> &' from 'const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'
error C2784:         with
error C2784:         [
error C2784:             _Ty=int
error C2784:         ]
VC\14.22.27905\include\xutility(1467): message :  see declaration of 'std::_Verify_range'
error C2784:  'void std::_Verify_range(const std::reverse_iterator<_BidIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_BidIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_BidIt> &' from 'const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'
error C2784:         with
error C2784:         [
error C2784:             _Ty=int
error C2784:         ]
VC\14.22.27905\include\xutility(983): message :  see declaration of 'std::_Verify_range'
error C2784:  'void std::_Verify_range(const _Ty *const ,const _Ty *const ) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'const _Ty *const ' from 'const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'
error C2784:         with
error C2784:         [
error C2784:             _Ty=int
error C2784:         ]
VC\14.22.27905\include\xutility(193): message :  see declaration of 'std::_Verify_range'
```

This is the code in `std::vector`:

```
// CLASS TEMPLATE _Vector_const_iterator
template <class _Myvec>
class _Vector_const_iterator : public _Iterator_base {
public:

    ...

#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0
    friend void _Verify_range(const _Vector_const_iterator& _First, const _Vector_const_iterator& _Last) {
        _STL_VERIFY(_First._Getcont() == _Last._Getcont(), "vector iterators in range are from different containers");
        _STL_VERIFY(_First._Ptr <= _Last._Ptr, "vector iterator range transposed");
    }
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0

    ...
}
```

The compiler seems only try to match these three prototype functions:

```
void std::_Verify_range(const std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> &,const std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,_Size> &);
```

and

```
void std::_Verify_range(const std::reverse_iterator<_BidIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_BidIt2> &)
```

and

```
void std::_Verify_range(const _Ty *const ,const _Ty *const ) noexcept;
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: "... can anyone help me to figure it out? can anyone help me to figure it out? can anyone help me to figure it out? ..." - *Don't do that*.

Comment: You could probably start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JesperJuhl, sorry,  it can not post the question if i don't write some more characters.

Comment: Then you should either find more relevant information to add or maybe reconsider posting the question.

Comment: @uneven_mark, thank you for edite the post format become better.

Comment: @uneven_mark, wow, change `std::_Verify_range` to `_Verify_range` then it work! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `friend` function declaration inside a class definition is placed into the enclosing namespace, but will not be found by name lookup in that namespace without an additional declaration in the namespace itself.

However, such a `friend` declaration can be found via ADL. ADL is only applied to unqualified names, not qualified names, such as `std::_Verify_range`.

Therefore I suggest simply using the unqualified name `_Verify_range` to refer to the function. If you include `using std::_Verify_range;`, then you can make sure that all the function overloads, including other ones from the namespace scope, can be found with the unqualified name `_Verify_range`.

I don't know whether this function is intended to be used by a program directly, but if it is, then apparently it is intended to be used this way or you forgot to `#include` a header with the namespace scope declaration.

The only documentation a google search gave me, is [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stl-features-and-fixes-in-vs-2017-15-8/), so I don't know. In any case be aware that this is not a standard C++ function, but MSVC specific and generally names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are implementation details that are not to be used directly.

Comment: i try to read `std::copy` function source code, i see it use `_Veirfy_range`. don't know and how it work, then i post this question, thank you a lot!!!